# NSTextView extract raw text content

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I want to find something that is the equivalent of [fieldName stringValue] for NSTextField, but for NSTextView. My understanding is that the stringValue property doesn't exist for the NSTextField because this field supports richer text.

Despite much googling I can't figure out how to just get the raw text content of the NSTextView. The only reason I'm using the NSTextView and not NSTextField is so I can have scroll bars...

Definitely a newb question!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say raw text content, do you mean a rich text string or a plain text string?

Comment: I mean plaintext string, thanks, that is an important clarification!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSTextField is a subclass of NSText, which has a "string" method. Try this:

```
[myTextField string];
```

It should work as needed.

Comment: I still get an error:2/17/11 12:02:39 AM app[30510] -[NSTextField string]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10011fa60 Also I am asking about NSTextView, not NSTextField... [object stringValue] works for NSTextField.

Comment: @ComputationalSocialScience I believe @sosborn meant `NSTextView` instead of `NSTextField`, and his answer is correct. `NSTextView` inherits from `NSText`, which provides a `-string` method that returns the receiver’s text without attributes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, meant to type NSTextView. Just as a side note, when you are looking at the API docs always look at the classes that it inherits from, there are usually a lot of helpful methods in the super classes.

Comment: Thanks! or the clarification. Your solution worked once I fixed another silly bug I had (assigning the outlet to a NSScrollView instead of NSTextView (inside the scroll view).